# Git Flow: Excluding certain feature in release branch

Tags: git, git-flow

Say there were 5 features merged into develop (eg A-B-C-D-E) but one of those features did not pass QA (eg C).

How do I start a release branch while excluding a feature at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I'd branch your `release` branch off from the point just before where the problematic feature branch (`C`) was, and then merge `D` and `E` into that `release` branch afterwards (assuming they weren't deleted already).

That way you will end up with `A`, `B`, `D` and `E` on `release`.

Comment: Wouldn't it become an issue when every time I'd create a release branch I have to start from B as long as C doesn't get fixed?